# How to stop a thread with a blocking call in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to stop a thread that has a blocking call inside it.  The loop below waits for a character to be read, and then processes the character.  I'm reading that Thread.Abort is bad practice, that essentially you should pass a signal (eg a boolean) into the thread and conclude your processing gracefully.

For most threads I've written I've followed this better practice by setting something like a stopThreadFlag boolean and checking for that in the thread loop. But in the routine below, if there is no data coming in, it blocks on "Read" and will never check the flag.

What is the right way to stop this thread?  Thank you.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = process.StandardOutput.Read()) >= 0)
    {
        // process character...for example:
        Console.Write((char)ch);
    }
}).Start();
```

Comment: Maybe you should kill the process?

Comment: In C# Thread.Abort (is that what you mean?) throws a PlatformNotSupported exception.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete

Comment: No, I mean `process` you are reading output from.

Comment: If I understand: I can actually end the process gracefully, but the Read thread will live on.

Comment: If you end process the `Read` should complete as far as I understand.

Comment: If I rerun and stop the parent process, the read processes actually seem to stack up in my Threads debug window, blocked on "ReadFile".  Maybe they don't do any harm since they are waiting for something that can't happen, but I'd like to clean them up if possible.

Comment: Can you switch to async code instead of a thread? ReadAsync takes a CancellationToken

Comment: Hmm, ... I would have expected that when you stop/kill the process, the StdOut will be closed and a pending `Read()` would throw an IOException or at least return -1 ?

Comment: If you want to kill this thread because your main process is exiting, then just exit your process and let the OS tidy things up  If you want to kill the thread because you want to restart it somehow, then that is bad (memory leaks, unknown process state, all kinds of bad things may happen) and you should come up with a different solution to your problem.

Answer (score -3):

> something like a stopThreadFlag boolean and checking for that in the thread loop

Yes, the general idea would look like this:

```
volatile bool stopThreadFlag  = false;

var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    while (!stopThreadFlag )
    {
        // Do what you need to
    }
});
thread.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop.");
Console.ReadLine(); 
stopThreadFlag = true;

thread.Join();
```

That being said, you should probably not be working directly with threads (this is rarely necessary and rather error-prone). Simpler to use a task with cancellation token:

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;
var task = Task.Run( () => 
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Do what you need to do
    }
}, token);

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop.");
Console.ReadLine();
source.Cancel();
await task;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right solution. The "do what you need to do" part in this case involves a call to `StandardOutput.Read()`, so it'll never get back to the `while` loop conditional until it receives input.

Comment: Although this is good advice John Wu, maybe an easier approach, yes as Stripling says the problem is that I am using a blocking function inside the while loop and cant check cancellarion.